# How to clear glSurfaceView that SupportMapFragment is drawing to?

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

## Question:

Is there a way to manually clear the OpenGL buffer that SupportMapFragment draws to before it makes subsequent glDraw() calls?

## Reason:

I have an ActivityGroup that contains two different embedded activities (only one of which can be shown on the screen at a given time). Here's a snippet of the layout code for it.

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_below="@+id/main_header"
 android:background="#313131" >

    <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/map_area_one"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:padding="5dp" />
    <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/map_area_two"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The views for both of the activities inside my ActivityGroup contain a SupportMapFragment. The first activity inside the ActivityGroup (with the smaller SupportMapFragment) gets displayed first and its view becomes a child of the FrameLayout with id map_area_one.

When the user presses a button, I launch the second activity inside the ActivityGroup (with the larger SupportMapFragment) and its view becomes a child of the FrameLayout with id map_area_one. I then hide the view of the first activity.

The problem I'm having is that even though the view for the 1st activity is no longer visible, I can still see the 1st activity's smaller SupportMapFragment (even though I cannot interact with it). I've attached images below.

I've arrived to the conclusion that this is because both SupportMapFragments draw the map using the same OpenGL SurfaceView. I'm pretty sure that for some reason, when I hide the first activity, the openGL buffer that SupportMapFragment is drawing to isn't being cleared. There are two reasons why I say this:

1. If I background the app and bring it back to the foreground, the smaller SupportMapFragment is no longer visible.
2. If I change the larger SupportMapFragment to a MapView that uses GoogleMaps Android v1 this issue is not present. This is because GoogleMaps Android v1 did not use OpenGL.

### Images

Screenshot right after user switches to second activity. Notice the first activity's SupportMapFragment (which is the smaller map strip towards the bottom) is still visible.
[image]

Screenshot right after I background the app and bring it back to the foreground. First activity's SupportMapFragment is no longer visible (which is how it should be). I'm assuming because the second activity called glClear() when the app was brought to the foreground again.
[image]

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I Would love to get that answer too, this is also happaning when switching MapFragments.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem eventually?

Answer (score 1):

Well I could at least delegate the problem by passing certain options at init time of the SupportMapFragment, concerning the zIndex:

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
options.zOrderOnTop(true);
fragmentMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hey thank you very much, that's worked for me. I have this problem only on devices <4.1. I have to put options as arguments onCreate() =>         args.putParcelable(MAP_OPTIONS, options); Where MAP_OPTIONS means "MapOptions" extracted from SDK SupportMapFragment class code